# PHP Print Included XML File

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to echo out an XML File via a PHP File. Like so:

Url visits viewxml.php?id=1

Php open a specific XML file, such as `"xmlfile_".$_GET['id'].".xml"` and prints it as if they are visiting the xml file itself.

The reason I'm using PHP is to do Session checks to make sure they are allowed to view the xml file.

This is how I am doing this:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
// send the saved XML file.
include "xmlfile_".$id.".xml";
```

Doing this gives me the following GC XML error: [image: error.]

*And there is nothing below it.*

I have tried different approaches, such as printing it or turning it into a string but then I have problems reading the XML on certain software. I am hoping one of you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: The end of a XML document must not mean the end of the file.

Comment: Try viewing the source to see if there is any bad markup

Answer (score 3):

`include()` will attempt to evaluate the file; if there's something in there that looks like PHP then it will corrupt your results.

Try using [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) instead; this will only output the file contents.

Comment: You might want to learn about [`include`](http://php.net/include) again - it's not that `readfile` would be wrong, just what you say about include.

Comment: yeah, he needs to try something like echo(file_get_contents("xmlfile_".$id.".xml"); if he wants to echo the xml to the client.

Comment: This worked like a charm and my software was able to read the .php as XML! Thanks! Stupid of me to think include() would do the job.

Comment: The problem with XML files and `include` is if short open tag is enabled on: `<?xml version="1.0"?>` on top of an XML file will trigger a parse error then.